# Подставить строку как название свойства в объекте

Tags: javascript, frontend

Есть объект в котором название свойства должно подставляться с прилетающей строки, то-есть оно должно выглядеть так:

```
string = 'sometext'
obj = {
  sometext: 23232
}
```

И при вызове свойства я должен подставить в его название строку:

```
console.log(obj.string)
////log 23232
```

И при этом чтобы оно желательно работало.
Возможно ли такое вообще на js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Возможно ли такое вообще на js?

Да.

[Доступность свойств](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2):

> Свойства объектов могут быть получены при помощи точечной нотации или
> **квадратных скобок**.

---

Как следствие:

```
    console.log(obj[string]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: @DeeEss  . Если ответ помог - можно ткнуть галочку напротив ответа